# How can I calculate distance between two nodes by TOA and TDOA in NS2?

Tags: tcl, wireless, ns2

I'm a beginner in ns2. I have two fixed nodes that periodically send a message in the network. These two nodes send their periodic messages simultaneously. Moreover, I have some mobile nodes in my network. I want to calculate distance between a mobile node and two fixed nodes preferably by TOA or TDOA method (we don't have mobile node position and nodes aren't equipped to GPS). I don't know how can I calculate TOA or TDOA between these nodes in NS2 with considering to estimating accurate distance. How can I do it? 
It's emergency for me please help me.

Comment: I think that sending and receiving time are fields of packet in NS2 and we can calculate difference between them, is it right? but I read before, calculation delays in source and target should be considered. also what should we do for TDOA calculation and so distance estimation with congestion and delay for receiving a packet?

Comment: @M.Alimohammadi, SO encourages people to try things themselves before asking for help.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Distance calculation

set nbr [open distance w]

puts $nbr "\t\t\t\t\t Detail of positions"

puts $nbr "\t~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~"

puts $nbr "\tNode\t\tNb node\t\tNode-Xpos\tNode-Ypos\tNb-Xpos\t\tNb-Ypos\t\tDistance(d)"

puts $nbr "\t~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~"

close $nbr

proc distance { n1 n2 nd1 nd2} {

  global c n bnd src dst j0 j1 

  set a 0

  set nbr [open distance a]

  set x1 [expr int([$n1 set X_])]

  set y1 [expr int([$n1 set Y_])]

 set x2 [expr int([$n2 set X_])]

  set y2 [expr int([$n2 set Y_])]

  set d [expr int(sqrt(pow(($x2-$x1),2)+pow(($y2-$y1),2)))]



      puts $nbr "\t$nd1\t\t$nd2\t\t$x1\t\t$y1\t\t$x2\t\t$y2\t\t$d"



  close $nbr
}



U can use above function to print distance node's of all nodes in ns2.
```

call the function"distance" to print neighbor list 
    for example,

```
for {set i 0} {$i <$val(nn)} {incr i} {
      for {set j 0} {$j <$val(nn)} {incr j} {

        $ns at 1.002 "distance $n($i) $n($j) $i $j" 
      }
    }
```

the above lines will print distance between all nodes at time 1.002

```
here val(nn) denotes number of nodes.
```

Comment: This solution is the easiest way possible for position estimation. Maybe my question is not clear. I edited my question and add a comment in parenthesizes.

Comment: When we have mobile nodes, network deployment is not static, so in real world in one side if we want to estimate distance or position of a mobile node by fixed nodes, we don't know real position (x,y) of mobile node and we don't want to get position information send by that (it is not trusted). On the other hand, If position estimation is doing by mobile node, we suppose it is not equipped to GPS and don't know its position (x,y) in the network to calculate its euclidean distance from fixed nodes.

Comment: So we should estimate its position (mobile node position) according to the received signal strength or the time difference of arrival or angle of arrival in receiver. Time Difference Of Arrival is more exact. Therefore I want to estimate distance between nodes by TDOA.

Answer (score 0):

RSS calculations are less accurate as compared to time based positioning algorithms and angle of arrival needs more processing and complex mathematical manipulations there its good to used Time of arrival or time difference of arrival for the distance calculation. But they need extra hardware implementations.